# Amazon S3 video control bar issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video, video-streaming, bucket

I have embedded my s3 bucket videos to my webpage, but the control bar to move video forward/backward is not working. Anyone can guide what to do? I have checked the video directly via url as well, and same issue. Looks like it is issue from s3 side. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that you don't see thumbnails when you slide along the timeline in the video controls on the webpage.

If so, then this functionality is usually provided in a separate track in the video container which has a set of thumbnail images at regular intervals, e.g. very 30 seconds, in the video.

When you slide along the timeline it displays the appropriate thumbnail for the time you are at on the timeline.

In other words, it is not downloading decoding and displaying a frame from the video, even though it looks this way to the user.

To support this functionality you typically need to have the thumbnails track in your video container.

Comment: https://nimb.ws/8A5aFN
The track ball to forward or backward video is not working actually.